# How to setup Jenkins service/system.d to automatically run at server reboot

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, reboot

I would like to set up a service on Ubuntu 18.04 to run automatically to start up Jenkins each time the server is rebooted.

My version of Jenkins comes from the Cloudbees distribution (https://downloads.cloudbees.com/cloudbees-jenkins-distribution/rolling/war/).

I can get Jenkins up and running manually, but in running tests with `sudo reboot` on the server to determine if Jenkins starts up automatically on a server reboot, it fails to start up. I've attached my jenkins.service file, which is located at `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service`

```
Description=Jenkins Service for
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=jenkins
Group=jenkins
ExecStart=java -jar /home/jenkins/cloudbees-jenkins-distribution.war --httpPort=8081
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've attempted to enable with service before rebooting via

```
sudo systemctl enable jenkins.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

Can anyone provide recommendations on how to get a Cloudbees Jenkins war file to start up automatically on a server reboot?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting the jenkins war file from the instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04. The jenkins war file installed at `/usr/share/jenkins`.

I made a copy of the jenkins/jobs folder that I had been using for the past month for the builds run through cloudbees jenkins. Deleted all references to cloudbees jenkins, installed new jenkins from the link, and copied back in my jobs folder.

This version of jenkins came with an init.d script, `/etc/init.d/jenkins` which was exactly what I needed to have jenkins start up automatically when the server reboot. Tested it by restarting the server, and when it came back alive again, Jenkins started right up.

So, I never did get the war file of Jenkins from Cloudbees going, but I found a workaround that got the job done that I needed it to.